# How to copy string before comma in file and paste it later in file after slash

Tags: linux, sed

How can I use sed
to copy before comma and paste after slash in a file?

Example:

```
text1,Information /
text2,Information /
text3,Information /
```

and I want

```
text1,Information /text1
text2,Information /text2
text3,Information /text3
```

Comment: `sed -e 's:\(\(.*\),.*/\):\1\2:'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with your example:

```
sed -r 's@(.*),(.*)/@\1,\2/\1@' <file_path>
```

The idea is that groups (between parentheses) are referenced in the substitution part.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/([^,]*).*/&\1/' file
```

Capture everything before the `,` and append to the end of the line.